# How to re-deploy Azure Resources using AzDevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, azure-resource-group

I have some azure resources (Function App, Cosmos etc) that I have successfully deployed in a resource group using terraform init-plan-apply in a Azure Devops Pipeline. From my local CLI I can change the resources in the main.tf and redeploy, presumably because I have the tf state locally. However, when I try to redploy using the pipeline I get the usual error

> Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/my
> -rg" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_resource_group" for more information.
> │

When I try to import using the config described [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform&ssr=false#overview) I get the unhelpful error

> ##[error]Error: There was an error when attempting to execute the process '/usr/local/bin/terraform'. This may indicate the process failed to start. Error: spawn /usr/local/bin/terraform ENOENT

Am I thinking about pipelines with terraform in the correct way? Should I be trying to import the resource group, or is there a better way to redeploy resources using terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the tf state is not saved on the Azure DevOps agents.

Common way is to use Azure Storage account to save the tf state.

You can find official Microsoft tutorial about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage?tabs=azure-cli).

More guides you can find [here](https://thomasthornton.cloud/2020/07/08/deploy-terraform-using-azure-devops/), [here](https://jacktracey.co.uk/terraform-with-azure-devops/) and [here](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/).

Comment: Thank you, I knew there had to be a right way of doing it